# Enable the Edit text field when checkbox is check

Tags: android, android-checkbox

```
<CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:letterSpacing="0.1"
            android:text="Mechanic"
            android:textColor="@color/darkgreen"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:paddingRight="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/cbmechanic"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
Mechaniccb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked){
                        Mechanicname.setFocusable(true);
                        Mechanicname.setCursorVisible(true);
                        Mechanicname.setEnabled(true);
                        //Toast.makeText(Mechanic_form.this,"Checked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        Mechanicname.setText("");
                        Mechanicname.setFocusable(false);
                        Mechanicname.setCursorVisible(false);
                        Mechanicname.setEnabled(false);
                        Toast.makeText(Mechanic_form.this,"Not Checked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Here is my xml code and following code is java. I want to enable text field when checkbox(Mechaniccb) is clicked but this code works only for one time. If checkbox is check and then unchecked this code is not working and I am unable to edit the edit text field(Mechanicname). Also when i run the application the edit text is still editable even it is unchecked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `android:enabled="false"` to your `EditText`, then add this :

```
Mechaniccb.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
            if (isChecked) Mechanicname.setEnabled(true);
            else {
                Mechanicname.setEnabled(false);
                Mechanicname.getText().clear();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have done the same thing except this android:enabled="false" in xml but its not working Still it is working for one check. When i check and then uncheck i am unable to write

Comment: I've tested it, and it's work just fine, can you please add your EditText XML

Comment: it works fine on multiple check and uncheck checkbox?
I have add another data in it. if you say i will add all xml and java code

Comment: Before I post the answer, I've tested it, it's work as expected, please add your full code, I want to give it a try

Comment: the code is long i cant post it. I will try on the other devices to see that it may not be compatible with my mobile

Comment: Yeah, or use gist

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but your code looks good and it will run